# Xamarin - Requesting camera permissions in WebView

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I want to make a container-app for my web application, and I decided to do so in Xamarin because the rest of the project is also .NET.

Initially I downloaded and setup the project from Xamarin Sample Pages:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview?tabs=windows

I simply changed a few variables in WebPage.cs: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/WorkingWithWebview/WorkingWithWebview/WebPage.cs

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace WorkingWithWebview
{
    public class WebPage : ContentPage
    {
        public WebPage()
        {
            var browser = new WebView();
            browser.Source = "https://xamarin.swappsdev.net";
            Content = browser;
        }
    }
}
```

Secondly I updated App.cs to suit my needs: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/WorkingWithWebview/WorkingWithWebview/App.

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace WorkingWithWebview
{
    public class App : Application
    {
        public App ()
        {
            MainPage = new WebPage();
        }
    }
}
```

And boom! I had an app.

Then came the real struggle. In the web application I can – when opening the site (https://xamarin.swappsdev.net) in the browser – click on a button which requests permissions from the device and then display the camera feed in the same window.

When doing the same action in the app nothing happens.

I then started googling for an answer and really didn’t find a lot. And the answers I found seems to be of an older version of Xamarin (?), since I wasn’t able to compare the files and structure in the answer compared to the one of the Xamarin Sample Page.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50560855

I tried implementing the answer from Robbit here. After a long struggle I managed to compile it and install it on my device but it doesn't actually ask for permissions.

I am at a loss and could need some help/guidance.

Comment: Hope this helps, https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/PermissionsPlugin

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Updated:**

In my previous answer, it shows how to add camera permission on webview.

The link you provided, it works now. https://xamarin.swappsdev.net/ It seems to provide a camera preview function. It need to check permissions on API 23+.

On Xamarin.Forms, you could use Permissions Plugin. https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/PermissionsPlugin

First, add the camera permission in Android Manifest.
Your Project.Android> Properties> Android Manifest> Required permissions> Camera. After that, it would generate the user permission in AndroidManifest.xml.

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

Create a Utils.cs.

```
public static class Utils
{
    public static async Task<PermissionStatus> CheckPermissions(Permission permission)
    {
        var permissionStatus = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(permission);
        bool request = false;
        if (permissionStatus == PermissionStatus.Denied)
        {
            if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)
            {

                var title = $"{permission} Permission";
                var question = $"To use this plugin the {permission} permission is required. Please go into Settings and turn on {permission} for the app.";
                var positive = "Settings";
                var negative = "Maybe Later";
                var task = Application.Current?.MainPage?.DisplayAlert(title, question, positive, negative);
                if (task == null)
                    return permissionStatus;

                var result = await task;
                if (result)
                {
                    CrossPermissions.Current.OpenAppSettings();
                }

                return permissionStatus;
            }

            request = true;

        }

        if (request || permissionStatus != PermissionStatus.Granted)
        {
            var newStatus = await CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionsAsync(permission);

            if (!newStatus.ContainsKey(permission))
            {
                return permissionStatus;
            }

            permissionStatus = newStatus[permission];

            if (newStatus[permission] != PermissionStatus.Granted)
            {
                permissionStatus = newStatus[permission];
                var title = $"{permission} Permission";
                var question = $"To use the plugin the {permission} permission is required.";
                var positive = "Settings";
                var negative = "Maybe Later";
                var task = Application.Current?.MainPage?.DisplayAlert(title, question, positive, negative);
                if (task == null)
                    return permissionStatus;

                var result = await task;
                if (result)
                {
                    CrossPermissions.Current.OpenAppSettings();
                }
                return permissionStatus;
            }
        }

        return permissionStatus;
    }
}
```

In MainActivity.cs, add the code in OnCreate method.

```
 Plugin.CurrentActivity.CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
```

OnRequestPermissionsResult is needed in MainActivity.cs.

```
public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, 
[GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
{
    PermissionsImplementation.Current.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
}
```

And then impletement it.

```
private async void _button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webView.Source = "https://xamarin.swappsdev.net/";//"https://test.webrtc.org/";

        var status = PermissionStatus.Unknown;

        status = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Permission.Camera);

        if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
        {

            status = await Utils.CheckPermissions(Permission.Camera);
        }

    }
```

[image]

I have upload on my GitHub. Check the folder. Test/CameraRuntimePermission_WebView/RuntimePermission

https://github.com/WendyZang/Test.git

**Edit:**

If you do not want to call this in button click event, you could delete the button in MainPage.xaml.

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
 public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        webView.Source = "https://xamarin.swappsdev.net/";
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        RunTimePermission();
    }

    public async void RunTimePermission()
    {
        var status = PermissionStatus.Unknown;

        status = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Permission.Camera);

        if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
        {

            status = await Utils.CheckPermissions(Permission.Camera);
        }

    }
```

[image]

Comment: Wendy, this is amazing! Thank you so much. Last thing, Is the button-click necessary or is it possible to trigger the permission-request when starting the app or have some kind of splash screen instead?

Comment: No, you could load without the button, but the runtime permission need to be ask after page loaded. I provide the code in my edit.

Comment: I'm not proud to admit this, but i missed the part where you moved `webView.Source = "https://xamarin.swappsdev.net/";` into the constructor. That took me a while to sort out why I was just looking at a white screen, but other than that it just works. Thank you so much for your help and time!!

Answer (score 4):

After following several guides to enable the WebView's camera, I have finally succeeded.

I followed all of the above steps, and despite getting prompts for allowing the camera I could never get rid of the permissions error (even when debug showed the permissions were granted). I then replaced the MyWebViewRenderer code (as given above by Wendy) with the following (as given on https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/183988/how-to-give-camera-and-microphone-permission-to-webview-with-xamarin-forms-on-android):

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomWebView), typeof(CustomWebViewRenderer))]
namespace App19F_8.Droid
{
    public class CustomWebViewRenderer : WebViewRenderer
    {
        public CustomWebViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.WebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                Control.SetWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient(MainActivity.Instance));
                Control.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
            }
        }
    }

    public class MyWebChromeClient : WebChromeClient
    {
        Activity mActivity = null;
        public MyWebChromeClient(Activity activity)
        {
            mActivity = activity;
        }
        public override void OnPermissionRequest(PermissionRequest request)
        {
            mActivity.RunOnUiThread(() => {
                request.Grant(request.GetResources());
            });
        }
    }
}
```

In case the link above becomes invalid, I should mention that in Android's MainActivity you should insert the following:

```
 public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        public static MainActivity Instance { get; private set; }
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            ...
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            Instance = this;
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            LoadApplication(new App());
        }
}
```

Now finally the camera is working :-) I'm not exactly sure what the culprit was in the previous code. Thanks a lot to Wendy, Yelinzh and all for the thorough responses.

Comment: Thanks for your input! You never know when this information becomes relevant, so I appreciate you taking your time to compile this answer.

Comment: It worked as expected man. Thank you for your valuable time to write this answer. Can you kindly pls tell me Is there any similar procedure required for ios?

Comment: @Thameem - Apologies for the very late response - Unfortunately I haven't tested this for iOS yet - only Android. Hope you came right...

Comment: It works!! It worths mention that it's needed to create a CustomWebView and use it like mentioned here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/hybridwebview

Comment: For IOS, you just need to grant Camera permission for you App, in my case I did not change anything else.

Comment: For iOS just need to add relavent permission strings in info.plist.[Ex: NSCameraUsageDescription...]

Comment: Didnt work for me in MAUI Android

Answer (score 2):

> I tried implementing the answer from Robbit here. After a long struggle I managed to compile it and install it on my device but it doesn't actually ask for permissions.

I try the code provided by Robbit from the link.
[Camera on Xamarin WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50553553/camera-on-xamarin-webview/50560855#50560855)

Actually, it works well. For better understanding, you could use the link below to check. https://test.webrtc.org/

If I use the webview to load the url directly, it would throw the error like below.

[image]

If I use the custom renderer from Robbit, it would ask for permission with the code in MyWebViewRenderer.

```
public override void OnPermissionRequest(PermissionRequest request)
        {
            mContext.RunOnUiThread(() =>
            {
                request.Grant(request.GetResources());

            });

        }
```

[image]

I have also check the link you used, nothing happened. The link would not open the camera in Android device.

[image]

**Usage of the code from Robbit.**

[image]

Create the MyWebView in your project.

```
public class MyWebView : WebView
{

}
```

Create the MyWebViewRenderer.cs in Android part of your project.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyWebView), typeof(MyWebViewRenderer))]
namespace WebViewDemo.Droid
{
public class MyWebViewRenderer : WebViewRenderer
{
    Activity mContext;
    public MyWebViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
        this.mContext = context as Activity;
    }
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.WebView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        Control.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
        Control.ClearCache(true);
        Control.SetWebChromeClient(new MyWebClient(mContext));
    }
    public class MyWebClient : WebChromeClient
    {
        Activity mContext;
        public MyWebClient(Activity context)
        {
            this.mContext = context;
        }
        [TargetApi(Value = 21)]
        public override void OnPermissionRequest(PermissionRequest request)
        {
            mContext.RunOnUiThread(() =>
            {
                request.Grant(request.GetResources());

            });

        }
    }
    }
}
```

Usage:

MainPage.xaml

```
 <StackLayout>
    <Button x:Name="_button" Clicked="_button_Clicked" />
    <local:MyWebView
        x:Name="webView"
        HeightRequest="500"
        WidthRequest="500" />
</StackLayout>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
private void _button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webView.Source = "https://test.webrtc.org/";//"https://xamarin.swappsdev.net/";
    }
```

You could download the whole project from GitHub folder `CameraRuntimePermission_WebView`. The Page1 is used to test the link with webview. The MainPage is used to test with custom renderer.
https://github.com/WendyZang/Test.git

Comment: Hi Wendy, thank you so much for your very detailed reply. However, I still experience the same old permissions-problem. I loaded in your "CameraRuntimePermission_WebView"-project and tried running it without any modifications. It compiles fine and shows me the blank button as you display in your gif, but it also tells me that it cannot access the hardware required in the webrtc-test.
After that I tried with my own link: This is the log from when I run it on my own link.
https://pastebin.com/3c9nKsTd

And this is where I usually run face-first into the wall. It never asks for permissions.

Comment: I have fixed error, i need some time to edit my reply. Wait for a monent.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable time for writing this answer. really appreciated!! It worked as expected..