# Xamarin Forms Ask User to Enable Location

Tags: xamarin.forms

The user gave location permission but the location is off. I wanna make a dialog box and ask the user to enable the location. I found a lot of similar questions but could not make it work. Can u help me? (Do I need to make 2 platform-specific implementations? or can I use xamarin forms?)

Comment: just use a DisplayAlert and prompt the user to enable Location

Comment: the result i'm trying to achieve is a display alert with 2 options. Ex: enable the location: yes // no. and when the user press yes,the location will be enabled from code by me.

Comment: You can't enable location if the user has disabled it.  Only the user can do that.  All you can do is prompt them to go do it.

Comment: But Waze is doing this

Comment: In Xamarin.forms, you could use the `Plugin.Permissions` to ask for the runtime permission. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Plugin.Permissions  Like Jason said, you could use a DisplayAlert or a button to trigger before you want to use the Location.  Here is a sample i done before to ask for the runtime permission. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59771557/xamarin-requesting-camera-permissions-in-webview