# Xamarin Forms WebView unable to use camera for HTML file input type

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-webview

My problem seems to be very straight forward, yet very confusing. I have a wrapper Xamarin Forms  application for my web app. The Xamarin app as expected, is just a WebView rendering the said web application.

On my web app, I have a HTML file input
`<input type="file" accept="image/*,application/pdf;capture=camera">`

When the webpage is accessed using the web browser (Android/iOS) it works as expected and provides the user with an option to use their camera for the picture. On the iOS version of the Xamarin Forms app, everything seems to be fine with the user still being presented an option to use their camera.

But on the Android version, I cant seem to get it to work. I have added the camera permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />` in the `AndroidManifest.xml`. Added run time checks to ensure the user either has already or can now agree to giving camera access to the app.

Not sure what I am missing but the camera option does not seem to open up for the Android version. I have seen some articles about WebRTC and using a custom renderer but not sure how and where to processed with those. Any suggestion to get this to work would really help

Comment: @Jason Thanks for the reference, the app is working as expected on iOS devices. Its the Android one that is giving me trouble

Comment: sorry, misread that.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59771557/xamarin-requesting-camera-permissions-in-webview

Comment: Tried this with no luck. It was useful to get the permissions set up and requesting it from the user on launch, but even with the permission granted it does not seem to launch the camera when needed

Comment: I've done it several years ago and wrote a thing about it, maybe it helps: https://blog.verslu.is/xamarin/xamarin-forms-xamarin/building-a-hybrid-app-with-xamarin-forms/