# choose camera or gallery webview

Tags: xamarin.forms, webview

i have webview for video call which is i am using in xamarin form app. In video call both user can share file, i need to add option for user to choose image from gallery or from camera where user can capture image and send.

here is my code

```
    public override bool OnShowFileChooser(Android.Webkit.WebView webView, IValueCallback filePathCallback, WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams)
    
    {





        this.message = filePathCallback;
        Intent chooserIntent = fileChooserParams.CreateIntent();
        chooserIntent.AddCategory(Intent.CategoryOpenable);
    
        this.mContext.StartActivity(Intent.CreateChooser(chooserIntent, "File Chooser"), filechooser, this.OnActivityResult);
        return true;
    }
    private void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        if (resultCode != Android.App.Result.Ok)
        {
            this.message.OnReceiveValue(null);
            return;
        }
        if (data != null)
        {
            if (requestCode == filechooser)
            {
                if (null == this.message)
                {
                    return;
                }

                try
                {
                    this.message.OnReceiveValue(WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams.ParseResult((int)resultCode, data));

                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                    throw;
                }
                this.message = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

with this code it only open gallery i need to know how i can add camera option with it

Comment: You could use the custom renderer. Please check the link below. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50553553/camera-on-xamarin-webview/50560855

Comment: i dont think u get my question

Comment: Could you provide more details for me?